# Using pointers to iterate through multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator

If you can use pointers to iterate through an array like this:

```
for (int *iter = arr; iter != std::end(arr); ++iter) {
    // code
}
```

How do you iterate through a multidimensional array with pointers (without using `auto`)?

**EDIT:** I am assuming this is an `int[][]` such as `{{3, 6, 8}, {2, 9, 3}, {4, 8, 2}}`

Comment: It might be the right time to who how your `arr` was actually declared.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you declared array as arr[][], and yes you can because they are stored sequentially in memory. You can do:

```
for(int * iter = &arr[0][0]; iter != &arr[0][0] + col * row; iter++)
//...
```

Comment: Is there anyway of finding `&arr[0][0] + col * row` without knowing the array size (`std::end(arr[2])` worked, but you require the number of arrays)

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
constexpr size_t rowCnt = 3, colCnt = 4;

int ia[rowCnt][colCnt] = { // three elements; each element is an array of size 4
     {0, 1, 2, 3}, // initializers for the row indexed by 0
     {4, 5, 6, 7}, // initializers for the row indexed by 1
     {8, 9, 10, 11} // initializers for the row indexed by 2
    };
```

Not using a type alias for the type of the loop control variables:

```
// p points to the first array in ia
for (int (*p)[colCnt] = ia; p != ia + rowCnt; ++p) {
    // q points to the first element of an array of four ints; that is, q points to an int
    for (int *q = *p; q != *p + colCnt; ++q)
        cout << *q << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

or easier using *auto*:

```
for (auto p = ia; p != ia + rowCnt; ++p) {
    // q points to the first element of an array of four ints; that is, q points to an int
    for (auto q = *p; q != *p + colCnt; ++q)
        cout << *q << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about trying like this:-

```
const int* d = data;
for ( int i = 0; i < width; ++i )
    for ( int j = 0; j < height; ++j )
        for ( int k = 0; k < depth; ++k )
            sum += *d++;
```

Check this [tutorial](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/06/c_c_tip_how_loop_through_multi_dimensional_arrays_quickly)

Comment: That's not strictly speaking a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: That's a hack that works only if the memory allocated for that multidimensional array is continuous. If you were to have an int ** array, you would have to allocate a block of multiple int * (one chunk of memory), then N allocations for each of those int * addresses (N chunks of memory).

Comment: It should work however for statically allocated multidimensional arrays like an int a[100][100]; declaration.

Comment: @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc *"That's a hack that works only if the memory allocated for that multidimensional array is continuous."* - That is definitely *not* a hack, since the memory of a multidimensional array is *always* contiguous.

Comment: @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc *"If you were to have an `int**` array, you would have to allocate a block of multiple `int*` (one chunk of memory), then N allocations for each of those `int*` addresses (N chunks of memory)."* - That would be an array of pointers pointing to dynamically allocated arrays, which has nothing to do with multidimensional arrays at all.

Comment: @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc *"It should work however for statically allocated multidimensional arrays"* - You cannot dynamically allocate multidimensional arrays anyway, `new int[4][4]` doesn't work.

Comment: How about declaring int a[4][4]; globally or locally inside a function? The memory allocated in that instance is continuous and you can do what the author of this answer hopes to do. However if you were to have to dynamically allocate a multidimensional array, you can only do it the way I mentioned. True, I didn't express myself clearly, but I wasn't wrong either. It all depends on how the data array is allocated in memory.

Comment: And by hack I meant that the code is not actually transparent to other programmers. It is not clear that data is a multidimensional array in the first place. If the code were to be reused and the data variable was allocated differently, at least in user-mode it would generate an Access Violation Exception.

Comment: @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc You just cannot dynamically allocate a multidimensional array, that's the whole point. What you described is *not* a multidimensional array at all.

Comment: In what sense is that not a multidimensional array? You can still access each member of the array by it's index, regardless of it's storage in memory. I can get the 5th element on the 5th line of a 2-dimensional array by using a[4][4] assuming the array's index starts at 0 for rows and 0 for columns.

Comment: @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc *"You can still access each member of the array by it's index, regardless of it's storage in memory."* - Of course you can, but that's not what it makes a multidimensional array, it's exactly that storage and type that you don't regard that make it a multidimensional array. I can access a `std::vector<std::vector>` the same way, yet that doesn't make it a multidimensional array, it's a vector of vectors.

Comment: I'm still not entirely convinced. Can you point me towards some reference on these matters?

Comment: @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc Christian is right. For references, check out common linear algebra libraries such as blas, lapack, atlas or armadillo. They all work on one contiguous block (a vector of appropriate size to be exact), which is *interpreted as* a multidimensional array.

Comment: @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc Well what do you want to know, the C++ Standard talks extensively about arrays (8.4.3) and `new` expressions (5.4.3). But it seems I was wrong. You can indeed dynamically allocate a multidiemsional array with `new int[4][4]` and this would then be a real dynamically allocated multidimensional array (for which this answer would work perfectly well, too, since it's, well, an actual multidiemsional array layed out in memory contiguously as an array of arrays).

Comment: I didn't know all of that. Thank you for the input. It seems strange to me because I don't have a mathematical background. I believed there was a distinction between how a multidimensional array is in memory and how it is functionally. I believed that if it works as a multidimensional array, it is a multidimensional array. Still, I believe that regardless of mathematical context, a programmer should never use a pointer incrementation over an access based by index for clarity when a multidimensional array is actually used.

Comment: I know that offset calculation by index is more costly to the CPU than a simple addition, but it may lead to errors if someone decides to change how the array is allocated. Typically, you want to do that dynamically since it's more likely to fit the array in separate blocks of memory if an entire continuous block is not available. I don't know much about branch prediction but I think that it may compensate for the cost of offset calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Improving texasbruce's answer(couldn't comment sorry) with `sizeof` trick, assuming array is statically allocated(dimensions are known at compile-time)
`for(int * iter = &arr[0][0]; iter != &arr[0][0] + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int); iter++)`
or `iter != (int*)((void*)&arr[0][0] + sizeof(arr))` if you're (void*) fan and hate any compile-time divisions

So you don't have to bother with array dimensions :)

Answer (score -1):

Probably something like this

```
   for (int **iter = arr; iter != std::end(arr); ++iter) {
        for (int *iter2 = *iter; iter2 != std::end(*arr); ++iter2) {
        // code
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems to produce the error `cannot convert type int (*)[2] to** int`

Comment: Yeah i didn't test it. Just removed one obvious bug. Try it now.

Comment: Still the same error, since obviously a multidimensional array cannot be converted into a multi-pointer. Can it be you're actually thinking about an array of pointers instead of a real multidimensional array?

Comment: Yes, I was assuming that. You never said how you declared the array.

Comment: "Multi pointer" is the common way to allocate multi dimensional arrays as it can be done dynamically. Please edit your question to include the array declaration / allocation this so there is no confusion on this.

Comment: @dr.mo But even for those your code doesn't make too much sense. What is `std::end(*arr)` doing in the second loop. And even more than that, how should `std::end` determine the end from a mere pointer, it *needs* an array as an array denotes its size as part of its type.

Comment: @ChristianRau I think it's not \*so\* obvious that needs to be said it's obvious.

Comment: "since obviously a multidimensional array cannot be converted into a multi-pointer". I mean this sentence.

Comment: @ChristianRau why don't you come up with the answer then?!

Comment: @dr.mo Because I don't know a good one or a better one than the already existing ones. Yet I don't see in which way this is relevant here. Does the fact that I have not given a better answer than *Rahul* or *texasbruce* make your answer magically work? I'm not sure.

Comment: @ChristianRau understood

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are simply talking about statically declared multi-dimensional arrays:

```
const int ROWS = 10;
const int COLS = 20;
const int DEPTH = 30;
int array[ROWS][COLS][DEPTH]; // statically allocated array
int i = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; ++col)
    {
        for (int depth = 0; depth < DEPTH; ++depth)
        {
            *(*(*(array + row) + col) + depth) = i++; // do whatever with it
            // is equivalent to array[row][col][depth] = i++;
        }
    }
}
```

If you need more levels, you just keep adding levels of pointer indirection.

Alternatively:

```
const int ROWS = 5;
const int COLS = 6;
const int DEPTH = 3;
int array[ROWS][COLS][DEPTH]; // statically allocated array
int* p = &array[0][0][0];
int c = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS * COLS * DEPTH; ++i, p++)
{
    *p = c++;
}
```

Since a statically declared array is going to be contiguous in memory, with the first element (`array[0][0][0]`) starting at the base address (`&array`), this works.

Declaring a multi-dimensional array dynamically is going to be a pointer to an array of pointers to (etc) to pointers to an array of `object_type`.  You can simplify that by using `std::vector` or `std::array` (if you know the size at compile time).

Not that these use pointers to iterate (at least not directly), but

**Vector/Array**

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > > array;
// or
//std::array<std::array<std::array<int, DEPTH>, COLS>, ROWS> array; // with some slight modifications
// fill in the vectors/arrays however you want

std::for_each(array.begin(), array.end(), [](const std::vector<std::vector<int> >& v)
{
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const std::vector<int>& a)
    {
        std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), [](int i)
        {
            std::cout << i << endl;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Uh, how do you index an array with a `int***`? And by the way, your `array` isn't an array at all, it's a pointer of pointers to pointers.

Comment: And exactly what you describe is *not* a multidiemsional array. It's an array of pointers pointing to dynamically allocated arrays (and so on). There is a definite difference because exactly this statement *"If you declare it int `array[10][20][30]`, you still (effectively) end up with an `int***`"* - Is plain wrong. Try `int array[10][20][30]; int ***p = array;` and see what happens. That's the whole point of the OP's question in the end.

Comment: And even apart from that your code doesn't make any sense for your described dynamic array of pointers to dynamic arrays either. Look at the part `int*** i= ...` [...] `array[i]` and tell me how that should even compile. What you probably meant was `*i` instead of `array[i]` (and likewise for the other iterators).

Comment: *"but for the most part, a statically declared multi-dimensional array will behave the same as a dynamically declared pointer to pointer to array."* - Just not for the part relevant to the question. Seriously, just try `int*** i = std::begin(array)` or `int*** i = array` or whatever and prepare for a nasty surprise.

Comment: I saw that you fixed part of your loops, but still seem to be reluctant to [try it out](http://ideone.com/Ddd8yg). How should `std::end` even find the end of a mere pointer. It is one of the few functions that really need an actual array and not just an array decayed to a pointer.

Comment: Iteration neccessarily needs information about the size of an array, information that is inherent to the type of a multidimensional array. But once you don't understand that array anymore as an array, but as a pointer of pointers (which for some problems might suffice) you loose exactly this information and cannot iterator over the array in a reasonable way anymore. What you have worked would be `int (*i)[20][30] = std::begin(array);` But that is a mess without `auto` anyway. But without a size there is no iteration.

Comment: Not reluctant, just didn't do it when I posted this yesterday.  Adjusted the answer to be more to your liking.

Comment: *"Adjusted the answer to be more to your liking."* - I don't know if I'm the only one who likes answers that actually work and are correct, but nevermind. Unfortunately now the answer doesn't address the question of iterating a multidimensional array with pointers at all. It's a normal index-based iteration, but at least it's not broken anymore.

Comment: Ah, now that is going into the right direction. (By the way, no need for the cast, since `&array[0][0][0]` is already `int*`.)

Comment: That was actually left over from when I had it as `&array` (which technically works, but isn't very clear).